# About array management in php

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a two-dimensional array with two columns, payment and day. The thing is that payments were not done everyday so my array only contains certain days in which payments were done.

> Payments------   Day
>
> 13000----------- 3
>
> 2500-------------  4
>
> 6700  ------------ 8

So, I want a monthly array with 31 fields for each day, if a payment was not done say, the first day then `array[0] = 0;`. I've thought  about using `in_array` to look for each day specifically :

```
for ($i=1; $i <=31 ; $i++) { 
    if(in_array($i, $payments))
}
```

But even if I find a day, how do I access array['payment'] field of that specific column?

Comment: Can you redesign the array? Make the day the key, not a column.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = ".$membership.
          " AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day"; my array was done using that query, so its not really me who designs it, is how i get my query data.

Comment: When you're processing the result of that query, and putting them into an array, make it an associative array instead of 2-dimensional.

Comment: Several answers clearly don't understand your data structure. Please post it as `var_dump()` output instead of your crude table.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `array_search()` which is like `in_array()` except that it returns the key?

```
for ($i=1; $i <=31 ; $i++) { 
    $row = array_search($i, $payments);
    if($row !== FALSE) {
        //Do something with $payments[$row]['payment']
    }
}
```

If I'm mis-understanding your array structure please tell me.

Comment: It's a 2-d array, not an associative array, so this won't work.

Comment: @FerSalas I just made a rather significant edit since I derped and explained what function to use and then didn't actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the array have the day number as the key and the payments as the value. Then you can check to see if the array contains any records for that with a simple `isset()`:

```
$payments = array(
    3 => 13000,
    4 => 2500,
    8 => 6700,
);
for ($i=1; $i <=31 ; $i++) { 
    if (isset($payments[$i])) {
         echo $payments[$i] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = ".$membership. " AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day"; my array was done using that query, so its not really me who designs it, is how i get my query data

Comment: That won't affect how the array is created. You just need to tweak the loop that makes the array.

Comment: how do i set the key to an array created dynamically? in your post you're declaring keys and values in an static array but mine is getting data from a query

Comment: Somewhere after that query is a loop that is creating the array you currently have. You have to modify that code to make the array I showed you.

Answer (score 0):

Create your array from the query in the following way:

```
$payments = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $payments[$row['day']] = $row['payment'];
}
```

Then you can use `isset($payments[$i])` to tell if you have a payment for a particular day.